# Performing operations in a Pivot

Tags: sql-server, syntax-error, pivot

I am trying to implement a `PIVOT` but I am having trouble performing basic operations in it.

Current table:

```
week_no  username  days      pick_count duration
------------------------------------------------
Week 50  Beck W    Wednesday 227        7978
Week 50  Beck W    Friday    320        7481
Week 50  Beck W    Friday    282        5718
Week 50  Cockram D Thursday  165        10478
Week 50  Cowell P  Thursday  145        14403
Week 50  Cowell P  Thursday  159        7450
Week 50  Cowell P  Friday    217        13101
...
```

Expected result:

```
week_no username  monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Week 50 Beck W    NULL   NULL    102       NULL     164    NULL     NULL
Week 50 Cockram D NULL   NULL    NULL      56       NULL   NULL     NULL
Week 50 Cowell P  NULL   NULL    NULL      50       59     NULL     NULL
...
```

The expected result should be calculated as followed: `pick_count * 3600 / duration`. That is the calculation I am having problem computing. When `PIVOT`ing like so

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        week_no,
        username,
        days,
        pick_count,
        duration
    FROM
        table
) AS src
PIVOT 
(
    SUM(pick_count) * 3600 / SUM(duration) FOR days IN (monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday)
) AS pvt
```

I get `Incorrect syntax near '*'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found what I was looking for. Indeed, all I needed to do was to compute the calculation in the `SELECT` instead of the `PIVOT`.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        week_no,
        username,
        days,
        SUM(pick_count) * 3600 / SUM(duration) AS pick_rate
    FROM
        table
    GROUP BY
        week_no,
        username,
        days
) AS src
PIVOT 
(
    MAX(pick_rate) FOR days IN (monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday)
) AS pvt
```

Answer (score 2):

`PIVOT` is not very flexible.

You can just use the old style cross tab approach.

```
SELECT week_no,
       username,
       SUM(CASE WHEN days = 'monday' then pick_count end) * 3600 
                    / SUM(CASE WHEN days = 'monday' then duration end) as monday,
       SUM(CASE WHEN days = 'tuesday' then pick_count end) * 3600 
                    / SUM(CASE WHEN days = 'tuesday' then duration end) as tuesday
/*TODO: Add other five days*/
FROM   YourTable
GROUP  BY week_no,
          username
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works. But I can't help thinking that it is not the best solution. Isn't there any way of doing that with a `PIVOT`?

Comment: @ArthurRey - No. `PIVOT` in SQL Server doesn't support multiple aggregations. It is just fairly inflexible syntactic sugar for this basic approach anyway. You could do two different PIVOTS but that would be much less efficient.